# Read lines from text file and if a specific word == 100, print the line

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a text file that i want to read using python. The text file contains words and a value such as (rt= 3.878). I want to write a script using python to read the text file and if rt in line is == 3.878, print that line.
I managed to write this piece of code so far.

```
    with open ('/home/Desktop/hello.txt', 'r') as f:
             f.readline()
             for line in f:
                     if 'rt' in line == 3.878
                              print(line)
```

This code returns nothing. Could anyone kindly point out what I might be doing wrong? thanks in advance!

Comment: Should that `if` not be ended with a `:`? Anyway, `if 'rt' in line` returns a boolean True or False, not a float number. (Also, where is the `100` from your title?)

Comment: @RadLexus: that will return an error… Not nothing

Comment: what is  `if 'rt' in line == 3.878` supposed to be doing? You also have a syntax error so your code would not even run.

Comment: the : at the end of 3.878 is a mistake above. I am including that in my text. @PadraicCunningham if 'rt' in line == 3.878: should be checking the value of rt and if it is equal to that value that I am searching for, it should print the line.

Comment: I think that this could return nothing because files are read as strings, not as integers, so perhaps change it to "3.878" rather than just 3.878

Comment: Add some input and expected output

Comment: basically I have a text file which contains lines like this: first line rt=1.2345, the line after rt=2.356, line after rt=5.245 etc.. I now want to read the text file line by line, and if one or more lines is greater than 3.587, i want to print those lines that are greater than 3.587

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can split each line on the `=` delimiter and then compare the second index of the result, after casting it from string to a float:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if float(line.split("=")[1]) == 3.878:
            print line
```

This is what `split` on `line` looks like:

```
line = "rt=3.878"
print line.split("=")[0] # rt
print line.split("=")[1] # 3.878
print type(line.split("=")[1]) # type 'str'
print type(float(line.split("=")[1])) # type 'float'
```

**Update** Replace you loop with this to only consider lines where the first string is "rt" and not e.g "ACCOUNT":

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.split("=")[0] == "rt":
            if float(line.split("=")[1]) == 3.878:
                print line
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please leave a comment stating what is wrong with this answer.

Comment: Hi @Plasma, this works perfectly! thanks. but what if i want all the 'rt' lines that have a value above 100.000 ? Could i do it using this method? thanks a million!

Comment: @joe, sure, just replace `if float(line.split("=")[1]) == 3.878:` with `if float(line.split("=")[1]) > 100000:`

Comment: I replaced the line but it returns nothing, not even an error. :/

Comment: @joe if it's not throwing an error, it means that it could not find any values above 100000 in the file. How exactly does your file look? Are there more entries on each line, or are there any spaces in the lines?

Comment: sorry about that but I realised I had no values above 100.000, hence that's why no errors were given. Now that this is settled, apart from rt=1.234 in my text file, I have other lines with text such as ANCOUNT = 2 and an error popped up could not convert string to float 'ANCOUNT'. Is there any way I could bypass this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the syntax error of missing `:`, `if 'rt' in line == 3.878` is a bug. The `in` operator checks membership and returns `True` or `False`, which are 1 and 0 respective in `int` context. So `==` will produce unexpected result.

Anyway, things won't happen magically just because we want them to. Some processing need to be done. If `n` is the number you want to match and assuming the lines are like `number = 1.234`

```
if line.split("=")[-1].strip() == str(n): # don't float() the left side
    # do something
```

Comment: thanks for this, works perfectly. However if I want all 'rt' lines that are above 100.000 in value, can I do it by replacing the == with a > ? Sorry i've just started using python and i don't know if this will work. thanks

Comment: @joe No. In that case `float()` the left side. `float(<left side>) > n`. Only `==` is problematic as they are floats. Give a thumbs up if it works :) .

Comment: should the line be something like this? if line.split("=")[-1].float(0) > 100.000 ? sorry about this but i couldn't understand what you mean by float the left side.

Comment: @joe I meant `float(line.split("=")[-1].strip()) > n`

Comment: @C Panda this returns the following error- ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2

Comment: @joe what did you get for `line.split("=")[-1].strip()`?

Comment: @joe **Some good news**.Don't have to change anything. Just change `==` to `>` in the original code. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As your file appears to have a very regular format, you could turn it into a dictionary:

```
with open('/home/Desktop/hello.txt') as f:
    result = {k:float(v) for k,v in (line.split('=') for line in f)}
```

Then directly access the key you're interested in and check its value:

```
if result.get('rt') == 3.878:
    print('rt=3.878')
```

You can quickly look up any key and its corresponding value without having to iterate through the whole file (or a saved sequence like a `list`) again.

If your file can have multiple lines with the same key, you'll need to group their values into a `list`, as dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. The common way to do this is with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections.defaultdict as dd
result = dd(list)
with open('/home/Desktop/hello.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        k,v = line.split('=')
        result[k].append(float(v)
```

You can then quickly look up any key and its corresponding values like you could with the basic dictionary. For example, you could print all values above a certain limit for a given key:

```
print(*(v for v in sorted(result.get('rt', '')) if v>100), sep='\n')
```

If you're really only interested in the `rt` key and in checking that it has a value of `3.878`, you could do that in a few ways.

First, simply reading the whole file:

```
with open('/home/Desktop/hello.txt') as f:
    print('rt=3.878' in f.read())
```

Iterating through the file and stopping when the desired value is reached:

```
with open('/home/Desktop/hello.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == 'rt=3.878':
            print(line)
            break
```

Eagerly evaluating the contents of the file and checking for the desired value in there:

```
with open('/home/Desktop/hello.txt') as f:
    print('rt=3.878' in {line.strip() for line in f})
```

Creating a dictionary is the most versatile approach, and the one I'd recommend. Iterating through the file and stopping when the desired value is reached is probably the best of the remaining approaches, as it will stop going through the file if and when it finds what you're looking for.

Note that you could also find this content by simply opening the file in a text editor and searching for `rt=3.878` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. The simple approach is often the best.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. Im pretty new to python so this helped me alot. Now if i want to print all the lines that have 'rt' above 100.000, could I still use this dictionary approach? thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

Well, may be:

```
with open ('/home/Desktop/hello.txt', 'r') as f:
         f.readline()
         for line in f:
                 if 'rt=3.878' in line:
                          print(line)
```

Comment: I trid this but this is just an escape way. Further on I want to include a line in my text that if rt = > 100.00: ... print all those lines

Comment: @joe: Well, I haven't read it in your question :). In that case, you'll have to use two steps. First find the line containing "rt=", then extract the number. It's very different from your question.